# Can I insert a PCIe x4 card into a PCIe x1 slot?

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express

I want to buy a PCIe x4 Wi-Fi/Bluetooth card, but the main board only has x1 slots remaining. Can I insert a PCIe x4 card into a PCIe x1 slot?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work from a PCIe perspective.  Having said that, there must be physical room to plug it in.  If the MB vendor didn't allow for a physical connection, don't force it.  If the x4 card will easily slide into the x1 slot, it should work.  Note that you will only have one PCI lane of bandwidth, so you may see a performance drop, but for a wifi card, I'd be surprised if you did.

Comment: And it will need to be an open-ended x1 slot.

Answer (score 1):

Spec wise it is possible, thy are "backward" compatible but you have to consider a few things:

- The layout of the motherboard must have enough room in order for the 4x card to fit, often there is some kind of chip or s.th. else in the way

  [image]
- The [slot must be able to take a x4 card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_(standard)), if it is not you must use an adapter or adjust the slot manually (physically cut it open at the end). This is not trivial, and I would not recommend it if you can't risk losing the main board. Note, that I never tried it myself, [but it is supposed to work](https://hardforum.com/threads/fitting-pcie-x4-card-in-pcie-x1-slot.1996656/). [Here another link.](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/pcie-4x-card-in-a-1x-slot.407263/)

  [image]
  [image]
- There might be a significant performance loss using a x4 card in a x1 slot up to the point where the card fails completely. As long as the Wi-Fi and connected Bluetooth devices are satisfied with less than 5Gbps total you should be good. Don't forget to check for the [**PCIe versions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions) as well.